# Overlapping of Images when using jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying to create a layout of some images(along with some text) using jQuery Masonary plugin.

The problem is that the images from bottom row overlay with images from top row.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        gutter: 10
    });
});
```

I also tried using imageLoaded but not sure how to use it right (used in fiddle).

The html layout of elements is below.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/zkrTbOKUt7w7x8TkLvR2qXZAKd3.jpg">
        <p> <a href="http://localhost/movie/101299">The Hunger Games: Catching Fire</a></p>
    </div>

   <div class="item">...</div>
   <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

The CSS applied is below.

```
.item {
   width: 185px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EVwXx/4/**

Comment: What have you expected? You've specified `height` for your image container in `.item` class. How should it look (may be sketch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting fixed height for `.item`. Removing it should help: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVwXx/5/).